# Serving static files from static domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My website is taking lot of time to download static files. To reduce requests to the same domain we decided to serve static files like scripts, styles and other images from static domain. In *BundleConfig.cs* --> `RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)` I tried this like below:

```
var staticDomain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["STATIC_DOMAIN"].ToString();
var version = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["STATIC_VERSION"].ToString();

//if static domain or version are not available,then use default.
Styles.DefaultTagFormat = "<link href='" + staticDomain + "{0}&vrsn=" + version + "' rel='stylesheet'/>";
Scripts.DefaultTagFormat = "<script src='" + staticDomain + "{0}&vrsn=" + version + "'></script>";
```

I created another website in IIS with static domain pointing to original website folder. When I loaded original website in browser, files are not downloaded. Error message says something like:

> Couldn't find file

Comment: Why don't you refer them directly in your views rather than adding to BundleConfig?

Comment: If i have to refer in views I will have to change hundreds of views. And I want to accomplish this task with minimal changes. So..

Comment: what is that {0} there for?

Comment: {0} will be replaced by MVC, it appends a querystring '?v=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.